# Javascript/Regex - Replace newline \n with p tag replace double new line with wrapped br tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm totally lost on how to write this regex. Basically what I need here is to wrap each line with a `<p></p>` tag and every double new line with a `<p><br /></p>`. So lets say I have the following string:

```
Hello World\n\nFoo Bar\nBas Baz
```

I need to write an output that would format it to the following:

```
<p>Hello World</p>
<p><br /></p>
<p>Foo Bar</p>
<p>Bas Baz</p>
```

Right now all I have is this but this doesn't work. Its not wrapping single lines with `<p>` tags

```
function textToHtml(text) {
  text = text.replace(/\n\n/g, '<p><br /></p>');
  return text;
}
--- 
textToHtml('Hello World\n\nFoo Bar\nBas Baz') 
// 'Hello World<p><br /></p>Foo Bar\nBas Baz'
```

Any nudge in the right direction would be much appreciated

Comment: Why don't you chain a second text.replace with the single \n something like `text.replace(/\n\n/g, '<p><br /></p>').replace('(.*)\n','<p>\1<p>')`

Comment: A single replace idea: [`s = s.replace(/.+|^/gm, m => '<p>'+(m?m:'<br />')+'</p>');`](https://tio.run/##FYtBCsIwEADvfcXeNiWaXMW2KfQg/sBLEWIMRdlkQ1J6EP8e620YZt52s8XlV1qP26lW8isUGACvnojhxpmec5zjhRkmm@c42bLDB7um@XdFZZ/IOi@0kt@7XsIBAgwGsE8GpQhjOGP/yKANthJ7vdt2fx3HwuQV8SJK29X6Aw) but I think it has some flaws, e.g. if you use it one strings only containing `\n` it will [add an extra `<p><br /></p>`](https://tio.run/##FctBCsMgEEDRvaeY3Sg2ui2NMRcJBSsiLRrFkaxyd5PuPg/@zx2OfPvWPh3PMVLoQLAAbjvOjP2TVAs1OR@4VvJ865gfkGGxgKZalDyv@YXm00BbFBKNvlXcry87lRRUKpGTmMe4AA) which might be undesired behaviour. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
function textToHtml(text) {
  const paragraphs = text.split('\n');
  const formattedText = paragraphs.map((paragraph) => {
    if (paragraph === '') {
      return '<p><br /></p>';
    } else {
      return `<p>${paragraph}</p>`;
    }
  }).join('');
  return formattedText;
}
var res=textToHtml('Hello World\n\nFoo Bar\nBas Baz');
console.log(res);
 ------
Output:

<p>Hello World</p><p><br /></p><p>Foo Bar</p><p>Bas Baz</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The following is only a "nudge" and is not complete in itself. It does not replace the newline characters in the text but just shows how lines can be wrapped by using `.+` to match one or more non-newline characters.

```
text = text.replace(/.+/g, '<p>$&</p>');
```

`$&` in the replacement string represents the whole match.

Anyway, I recommend Sandeep Singh's approach.

---

Complete solution:

```js
function textToHtml(text) {
  return text
    .replace(/.+/g, '<p>$&</p>')
    .replace(/(?<=\n|^)(?=\n|$)/g, '<p><br /></p>');
}

console.log(textToHtml('Hello World\n\nFoo Bar\nBas Baz'));
```

Comment: @Yogi Added full solution for completeness. Note that, unlike some answers, some newlines are retained as OP seems to want.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use regex for this:

```js
const test = 'Hello World\n\nFoo Bar\nBas Baz';

const toHtmlP = (str) => test.split('\n').map(p => '<p>'+(p.length ? p : '<br />')+'</p>').join('');

console.log(toHtmlP(test));
```

Also, as you can see on the [jsperf benchmark](https://www.jsperf.net/daxafi), the version without regex is faster:
[image]